# Web Service with Android KSoap returns anyType

Tags: android, xml, ksoap

I am currently doing an Andrid project which deals with the clients webservice. To cut the story short, when running the webservice as a test, the browser displays proper well formed XML but on the Android KSoap it returns AnyType{resp=200; etc etc} so I found out that the httpTransport.debug = true has to be on and using httpTransport.responseDump and it will form full XML including the HTML tags such as

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/`

and so on, but this is not the case from the browser and I need the browser's output format.

Am I suppose to do something else?

Comment: What does it say the size is for the soap response? Can you confirm that you're making a correct call and not getting an exception of sorts?

Answer (score 0):

transport.call(soap_action, envelope);
 result =  (SoapObject) envelope.getResponse();
 result.getProperty(0).toString();//will give you first element of returned objects